# gem sources -a not working also SSL error is therre

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Not able to add any gem sources thus can't do gem install. See command output

Adding using https://rubygems.org **failed**, see output

```
C:\>gem sources -a https://rubygems.org
Error fetching https://rubygems.org:
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server 
    certificate B: certificate verify failed 
    (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Adding using http://rubygems.org **failed**, see output

```
C:\>gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
Error fetching http://rubygems.org:
        server did not return a valid file 
        (http://api.rubygems.org  /specs.4.8.gz)
```

**No Sources In System**, See Command Output
    C:>gem sources
    *** CURRENT SOURCES ***

Comment: **SOLVED** gem 2.5.1 got installed due to MSI installer of ruby 2.3.1p112 on windows 10 x64 so we need to exclusively update gem version by ```gem install rubygems-update``` thereafter ```update_rubygems```. This is available [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1533)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gem 2.5.1 got installed due to MSI installer of ruby 2.3.1p112 on windows 10 x64 so we need to exclusively update gem version by `gem install rubygems-update` thereafter update_rubygems. This is available [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1533)